# Get array item based on index

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I am trying to get an item from a char array based on the index that I have. I have used code earlier to get the index of a specified item but now I want the opposite, to get the item of the specified index. I have tried a few things but can't get it working.

I would like something like this:

```
char arrayChar = Array.GetItem(index [i]) // I know this isn't right but just so you get the idea.
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your char array is called `ArrayOfChars` and the index is `i`. It should be as simple as

```
char arrayChar = ArrayOfChars[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayChar = yourArray[index];
```