# How can I open a new tab in Selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, webforms, remotewebdriver

I have a driver same code as below.
And now I want to open a new tab and navigate my new tab to another url.
But I get one Error

> System.InvalidOperationException: missing field `handle` at line 3
>   column 1

```
DesiredCapabilities Capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
Capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");

string GridURL = "http://localhost:4545/wd/hub";
Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(GridURL), Capabilities);
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://URL1.com");
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open('URL2.com', '_blank');");

// this line have error 
//System.InvalidOperationException: missing field `handle` at line 3 column 1
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.First());
```

Comment: It might be versions mismatch, what are the versions you are using?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) class in order to ensure that second tab is open and ready and it's [handle](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Handles_and_Data_Types#HANDLE) has been added to [WindowHandles](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_WindowHandles.htm). See [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more information on the concept.
2. I don't see `First()` method in the [ReadOnlyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) so try accessing the handle in [array-like manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620648/get-array-item-based-on-index)

Example code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(d => d.WindowHandles.Count == 2);
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles[1]);
Console.WriteLine(Driver.Title);
```

Comment: [First()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8) is from Linq. And if the problem was that there was only one item in `WindowHandles` it would have thrown `index out of bounds exception`.

Comment: it is does not worked